# How to fix the vertex detection issue when drawing on canvas?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, graph, charts

My task is to create a React application in which there is a place for drawing and the user must draw a graph there, after the user draws, I need the highest and lowest points to be determined on this graph.

In part, I was able to implement this, but there is a problem. When the user draws slowly, everything works as it should - the top and bottom points are determined correctly.
**For example when drawing slowly:**
[image]

But as soon as the user starts to draw the graph quickly or abruptly, the points are determined incorrectly.
**Example:**
[image]

**The code looks like this:**

```js
import { createRef, MouseEvent, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

type Point = { x: number; y: number; };


const CANVAS_SIZE: [ width: number, height: number ] = [ 980, 600 ];
const LINE_STROKE =
    {
        width: 5,
        color: "#FFFFFF"
    } as const;


function findPeakIndex(points: Point[])
{
    let maxIndex: null | number = null;
    let maxValue = -Infinity;
    for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
    {
        if (points[ i ].y > maxValue)
        {
            maxIndex = i;
            maxValue = points[ i ].y;
        }
    }
    return maxIndex;
}

function findValleyIndex(paths: Point[])
{
    let minIndex: number | null = null;
    let minValue = Infinity;
    for (let i = 0; i < paths.length; i++)
    {
        if (paths[ i ].y < minValue)
        {
            minIndex = i;
            minValue = paths[ i ].y;
        }
    }
    return minIndex;
}

function findPeaksAndValleys(path: Point[])
{
    // Smooth path with moving average filter
    const smoothPath = path.map((point) => point.y);
    const smoothWindowSize = 20;
    for (let i = 0; i < smoothPath.length; i++)
    {
        const windowStart = Math.max(0, i - smoothWindowSize);
        const windowEnd = Math.min(smoothPath.length - 1, i + smoothWindowSize);
        const window = smoothPath.slice(windowStart, windowEnd + 1);
        const windowSum = window.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
        smoothPath[ i ] = windowSum / window.length;
    }

    // Find peaks and valleys based on filtered path
    const peaks: Point[] = [];
    let peakStart: null | number = null;
    let peakEnd: null | number = null;
    let peakMax = -Infinity;
    let peakThreshold = 0.05; // Initial threshold for peak detection

    for (let i = 0; i < smoothPath.length; i++)
    {
        const value = smoothPath[ i ];
        if (value > peakMax)
        {
            peakMax = value;
            peakEnd = i;
        }
        else if (peakStart !== null && peakEnd !== null)
        {
            const peakIndex = findPeakIndex(path.slice(peakStart, peakEnd + 1));
            if (peakIndex !== null)
            {
                peaks.push(path[ peakStart + peakIndex ]);
            }
            peakStart = null;
            peakEnd = null;
            peakMax = -Infinity;
            peakThreshold = 0.05; // Reset threshold for peak detection
        }
        if (peakStart === null || value > peakMax - peakThreshold * peakMax)
        {
            peakStart = i;
            peakMax = value;
        }
        else if (value < peakMax - peakThreshold * peakMax)
        {
            peakThreshold = 0.01; // Decrease threshold for peak detection
        }
    }

    const valleys: Point[] = [];
    let valleyStart: null | number = null;
    let valleyEnd: null | number = null;
    let valleyMin = Infinity;
    let valleyThreshold = 0.05; // Initial threshold for valley detection

    for (let i = 0; i < smoothPath.length; i++)
    {
        const value = smoothPath[ i ];
        if (value < valleyMin)
        {
            valleyMin = value;
            valleyEnd = i;
        }
        else if (valleyStart !== null && valleyEnd !== null)
        {
            const valleyIndex = findValleyIndex(path.slice(valleyStart, valleyEnd + 1));
            if (valleyIndex !== null)
            {
                valleys.push(path[ valleyStart + valleyIndex ]);
            }
            valleyStart = null;
            valleyEnd = null;
            valleyMin = Infinity;
            valleyThreshold = 0.05; // Reset threshold for valley detection
        }
        if (valleyStart === null || value < valleyMin + valleyThreshold * valleyMin)
        {
            valleyStart = i;
            valleyMin = value;
        }
        else if (value > valleyMin + valleyThreshold * valleyMin)
        {
            valleyThreshold = 0.01; // Decrease threshold for valley detection
        }
    }

    return { peaks, valleys };
}

export default function App() {
    const loadRef = useRef<boolean>(false);
    const canvasRef = createRef<HTMLCanvasElement>();
    const contextRef = useRef<CanvasRenderingContext2D>();
    const [ isDrawing, setIsDrawing ] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [ path, setPath ] = useState<Point[]>([]);

    // useEffect(() => console.info(path), [ path ]);
    // Effects 
    useEffect(() =>
    {
        function prepareCanvas()
        {
            const canvas = canvasRef.current!;
            canvas.width = CANVAS_SIZE[ 0 ];
            canvas.height = CANVAS_SIZE[ 1 ];
            canvas.style.width = CANVAS_SIZE[ 0 ] + "px";
            canvas.style.height = CANVAS_SIZE[ 1 ] + "px";

            const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")!;

            ctx.lineCap = "round";
            ctx.shadowColor = "rgba(126, 196, 255, 0.102)";
            ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
            ctx.shadowOffsetY = 5;
            ctx.shadowBlur = 10;

            contextRef.current = ctx;
        }

        if (loadRef.current === false)
        {
            loadRef.current = true;
            prepareCanvas();
        }
    }, []);

  // Handles
    function clearCanvas()
    {
        contextRef.current!.clearRect(0, 0, canvasRef.current!.width, canvasRef.current!.height);
  }
  
    function startDrawing({ nativeEvent }: MouseEvent<HTMLCanvasElement>)
    {
        if (!contextRef.current)
        {
            return;
        }

        clearCanvas();

        const { offsetX: x, offsetY: y } = nativeEvent;
        const ctx = contextRef.current;

        ctx.strokeStyle = LINE_STROKE.color;
        ctx.lineWidth = LINE_STROKE.width;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x, y);

        setIsDrawing(true);
        setPath([ { x, y } ]);
    }

    function finishDrawing()
    {
        if (!contextRef.current)
        {
            return;
        }

        setIsDrawing(false);

        const ctx = contextRef.current;
        const { peaks, valleys } = findPeaksAndValleys(path);
        
        ctx.closePath();

        // Draw incursions
        const circleRadius = 10;

        // Peaks
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        peaks.forEach((peak) =>
        {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(peak.x, peak.y, circleRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.fill();
        });

        // Valleys
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
        valleys.forEach((valley) =>
        {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(valley.x, valley.y, circleRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.fill();
        });
    }

    function onDraw({ nativeEvent }: MouseEvent<HTMLCanvasElement>)
    {
        if (!contextRef.current || !isDrawing)
        {
            return;
        }

        const { offsetX: x, offsetY: y } = nativeEvent;
        const ctx = contextRef.current;

        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.stroke();

        setPath((prevPath) => [ ...prevPath, { x, y } ]);
    }

    // Render
    return (
        <canvas
            ref={canvasRef}
            onMouseDown={startDrawing}
            onMouseUp={finishDrawing}
            onMouseLeave={finishDrawing}
            onMouseMove={onDraw}
            style={{ backgroundColor: "#FFF", borderRadius: "16px", border: "1px solid black" }}
        />
    );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Summing up, I need to fix the error in determining the points when quickly drawing the graph. Has anyone come across this and know how to fix this error? I will be grateful for the help.

Comment: You have the best written question I've ever seen from a new user. +1

Answer (score 0):

An effective and simple way to find peaks, both positive and negative, is to look for changes in the sign of the slope.

Assume that V(t) is the smoothed value at time t.

```
IF (Vt-V(t-1)) * ( V(t+1) - V(t) ) < 0
   THEN T is a peak
```